# Returning a value that matches 2 conditions in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, lookup

I am trying to write a formula in Google sheets that returns a value if 2 conditions, 1 horizontal and one vertical are met.
I tried index match but it didn't work with 2 conditions

Here is a screen shot with an example:

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7pPW.png)

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet so we have some data to work with.

Comment: Here is the data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_z2JiLrEMr48a-FtBXnvUyT8TxpnCljM2rYwimRtazs/edit?usp=sharing.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what `INDEX`/`MATCH` exactly does:

```
=INDEX(E9:K14,MATCH(F3,E9:E14,0),MATCH(F2,E9:K9,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach

```
=filter(filter(F9:K14, F9:K9=F2), E9:E14=F3)
```